# How to find the sum of each row for a multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby

I would like to find the sum of each row of a multidimensional array, and have the sums an array, e.g., for `[[1,2,3],[1,1,1]]`, I would like to get `[6,3]`.

I tried the following:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]]
print arr.each{|row| row.each{|column| puts column}}
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
2
1
3
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 3]]
```

I am struggling with it. I still don't fully understand `each` iterators. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For ruby 2.4.0 or newer

```
a.map { |suba| suba.sum }
```

or simply

```
a.map(&:sum)
```

for ruby prior to 2.4.0

```
a.map { |suba| suba.inject(0, :+) }
```

Comment: I'm using a cloud IDE and it returns the value:                                    undefined method`sum' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
(repl):10:in `map'
(repl):10:in `<main>'

Comment: my pleasure sir :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[[1,2,3],[1,1,1]].map{|a| a.inject(:+)} # => [6, 3]
```

If there is a possibility that any of the sub-array can be empty, then you need to add the initial `0`, as Ursus pointed out.

```
[[1,2,3],[1,1,1]].map{|a| a.inject(0, :+)} # => [6, 3]
```

Comment: works perfectly. Looks like I'm gonna have to learn about .map and .inject

Comment: @sawa use `inject(0, :+)` or you get `nil` for an empty array

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1,2,3],[1,1,1]].map { |a| a.inject(0, :+) } # => [6 , 3]
```

1. map changes each element to the return value of this elements block
2. get the sum for each array with inject(:+)
3. use inject(0, :+) to set 0 instead of the first element as the start value (handles empty inner array)

see:

- [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)
- [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

Comment: `inject` without `0` doesn't set `nil` as the start value.

Comment: you're right. It would just be nil otherwise on an empty array, because the "first" is nil

Comment: As I wrote, the "first" is not `nil`. If it were, then it would raise an error as method `nil.+()` is not defined. There is no "first".

Comment: @sawa that is why i wrote "first" in quotionsmark, in the sense that `[].first` returns `nil`. It would also not raise an error, as `+` is not executed by `inject`, if the `Enumarable` has length 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

"How to find the sum of each row"

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [1,1,1]]
```

`print arr.each{|row|` <-- here you have each row

So now `row` contains `[1,2,3]` initially. As others have mentioned, you can apply a `sum` here. (You don't need the leading `print`).

```
arr.each{|row| puts row.sum}
```

Result:

```
6
3
```

But a better way to do it is with `map`. As I told a Ruby newbie many years ago, think of `map` when you want to change every element to something else, in other words a "1:1 mapping" of input to output. In this case the output is `row.sum`:

```
sums = arr.map{|row| row.sum}
```

Result:

```
[6, 3]
```